# Smooth scrolling problem with Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an image carousel in HTML/CSS/JavaScript using CSS properties like "scroll-snap-type," "scroll-snap-align," and "scroll-behavior" to achieve a centered scrolling effect for my images. I'm using a JavaScript function to enable smooth scrolling with mouse drag.

It works perfectly on Firefox, but not at all on Chrome and Edge. The scrolling is not smooth and jumps from one image to another. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the snippet :

```js
// ----------------------- //
// ------ FONCTIONS ------ //
// ----------------------- //

// DISABLE SELECTION FOR ELEMENTS
function clicAndDrag() {
    const childs = Array.from(document.querySelector('.carousel').children)
    childs.forEach(undrag)
    function undrag(e) {
        e.setAttribute("draggable", "false")
        e.style.cssText="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" 
        e.unselectable="on"
        e.style.onselectstart = "return false;"
        e.style.onmousedown = "return false;"
        const subchilds = Array.from(e.children)
        subchilds.forEach(undrag)
    }

    // GRABBING EFFECT
    const container = document.querySelector('.carousel')
    let mousedown = false;
    document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {mousedown = true});
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {mousedown = false});
    let firstpos;
    let currentpos;
    let currentscroll;
    // Remove smooth scrolling and scrol-snap for free scrolling and get the scroll/cursor positions
    container.addEventListener('mousedown', down)
    function down(e) {
        currentscroll = container.scrollLeft
        firstpos = e.clientX
        container.style.cssText="scroll-behavior: initial; scroll-snap-type: none;"
        childs.forEach(e => {
            e.style.cssText="scroll-snap-align: none;"
        })
    }
    container.addEventListener('mousemove', move)
    function move(e) {      //  Grab Effect
        if (mousedown === true) {
            currentpos = e.clientX
            const moved = currentpos - firstpos
            container.scroll((currentscroll - moved), 0)
        }
    }
    // Add smooth scrolling with scroll-snap on releasing mouse
    container.addEventListener('mouseup', up)
    function up() {
        container.style.cssText="scroll-snap-type: x mandatory; scroll-behavior: smooth;"
        childs.forEach(e => {
            e.style.cssText="scroll-snap-align: center;"
        })
    }
}

// ----------------------- //
// ------ LANCEMENT ------ //
// ----------------------- //

// Gestion du javascript si activé
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    
    var htmlClass = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    htmlClass.classList.replace("no-js", "has-js");
})

// Lancement des fonctions lorsque la page est chargée
window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
    clicAndDrag();
});
```

```css
/* -------------------------------- */
/* ------------ GLOBAL ------------ */
/* -------------------------------- */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#global {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* -------------------------------- */
/* ------ NAVIGATION EN HAUT ------ */
/* -------------------------------- */

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #111;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3125em; /* Equivalent a 21px standard*/
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.75em; /* Equivalent a 12px standard*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.is-active {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.menu li {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.social {
    display: block;
}

.serie {
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* -------------------------------- */
/* ----------- CAROUSEL ----------- */
/* -------------------------------- */

.carousel {
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100svh - 80px);
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Masquage de la scrollbar si javascript activé */
.has-js .carousel {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}

/* Idem mais pour navigateurs webkit */
.has-js .carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.carousel-item {
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-right: 30px; /* Espacement entre chaque image */
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.carousel-item img {
    height: 100%; /* Redimensionnement par rapport à la hauteur du carrousel */
    max-height: 1400px;
    width: auto; /* Pour conserver les proportions de l'image */
}

.carousel-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 50%; /* Ajuste la marge pour centrer correctement la dernière image */
}

.caption {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 0.75em; /* Equivalent a 12px standard*/
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    height: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
<head>
    <title>Alan Renault - Photographie</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="global">

        <!-- NAVIGATION EN HAUT DE LA PAGE -->
        <nav>
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">Alan Renault</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><span class="serie">Séries :</span></li>
                <li><a class="is-active" href="index.html">2023</a></li>
                <li><a href="2022.html">2022</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">&Agrave; propos</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <a class="social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alanrenault/" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- CARROUSEL DE PHOTOS -->
        <div class="carousel" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7064.jpg" alt="Image 1"><span class="caption">Légende</span></div>
            <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7048.jpg" alt="Image 2"><span class="caption">Légende</span></div>
            <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7977.jpg" alt="Image 3"><span class="caption">Légende</span></div>
            <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7940.jpg" alt="Image 3"><span class="caption">Légende</span></div>
            <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_6932.jpg" alt="Image 3"><span class="caption">Légende</span></div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            Copyright &copy; 2023 - Alan Renault
        </footer>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the smooth-scrolling script you're using, and why did you feel you needed it? In any case, the modern CSS rules for scroll behaviour and snapping make it so you _don't_ have to use a third-party library for these things, ideally. I would expect that after trying to optimize with these native rules, if it's not working out, only then you'd leverage a 3rd-party library. I'd expect that there maybe conflicts between the library and your use of CSS rules, so do one or the other.

Comment: In any case, most CSS is reliably consistent across all browsers/os's/devices, but _scrolling_ is especially one area of CSS where you need to expect differences. You must develop in a cross-browser way. For websites, the safe bet is usually develop Chrome-first, then optimize for iOS/Safari. The Firefox user base is almost irrelevant.

Comment: My script is designed to achieve a smoother scrolling effect using drag and slide with the mouse. When you click and drag, the scroll-snap-type is deactivated to simulate a 'free mode' in the scroll. Upon releasing the click, the scroll-snap-type becomes mandatory again, ensuring the image scrolls to the correct position (centered).